# Retrieving data in some fixed interval of time

Tags: javascript, jsp, model-view-controller

I am currently working on a project based on MVC framework. having a front-end designed in jsp. the page shows count of some notifications. 
Now I want to achieve a functionality, i want my page to retrieve data in fixed interval of time and refresh the count on the page, until some "flag" is set.
so, any help how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var count = 0;

var testInterval = setInterval(function () {
    // Retrieve data here

    // Update count
    console.log(count);
    count += 1;

    // After some count limit
    if (count >= 10) {
        clearInterval(testInterval)
    }
    
}, 100)
```

If this is the answer you want, press the green tick on the left.